# stdClass and anonymous function

Tags: php, stdclass

I can do this with anonymous function

```
 $func = function() {
      return "Hello World";
 };
 var_dump($func());
```

However, I cannot do this

```
$namespace->func = function() {
      return "Hello World";
 };
 var_dump($namespace->func());
```

I will get this error

> Call to undefined method stdClass

The workaround that I have discovered so far is to use another variable

```
$temp = $namespace->func;
var_dump($temp());
```

Is there a way that I can do it in one line?

Comment: Do you actually need the object type? If this is just for namespacing, an array could handle the same thing.

Comment: I just want to discover all the possibility. Thanks for your suggestion @Yoshi. That's why I love Stackoverflow because not only I get the answer, I also get practical suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`__invoke()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) :

```
// declare $namespace to be conform to strict standards
$namespace = new StdClass();

$namespace->func = function() {
      return "Hello World";
 };
var_dump($namespace->func->__invoke());
```

That's because even if a property `func` exists which is a closure, PHP will not check if it is a closure and call it.

Comment: A quick question, Is it okay not to use `new StdClass();`? Or it is good practice to use it?

Comment: increase your `error_reporting` to `E_STRICT | E_ALL` and you will see that message. From my own experience I can say that it is always the right way to be conform with strict standards. This will prevent you from many headaches.